# How to build interactive scrolling landing page with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How to implement directive for landing page, so that when scrolling it will add `.fadein` class to the `.box` element when window achieve given section height? I found many examples with jQuery or ScrollMagic.js, but can't find any example with angularjs.

I've added basic example to show the idea:

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("scroll", function($window) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
      scope.fadein = true;
    });
  };
});
```

```css
body,
html,
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
#example-1 {
  background-color: #FC6E51;
}
#example-2 {
  background-color: #4FC1E9;
}
#example-3 {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
.fadein {
  display: block;
}
.center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<span ng-app="myApp" scroll>

  <section id="example-1" class="container">
    <div class="box center fadein">
      <h1 class="">Show me when scrolled to this section</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="example-2" class="container">
    <div class="box center">
      <h1 class="">Show me when scrolled to this section</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="example-3" class="container">
    <div class="box center">
      <h1 class="">Show me when scrolled to this section</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with this:

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("scroll", function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var offsetTop = element[0].offsetTop,
                offsetHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;

            checkScene();

            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                checkScene();                     
            });

            function checkScene() {
                var bodyScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;

                if (bodyScrollTop >= offsetTop
                    && bodyScrollTop <= offsetTop + offsetHeight) {
                    element.addClass('fadein');
                } else {
                    element.removeClass('fadein');
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```css
body, html, .container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}

#example-1 {
    background-color: #FC6E51;
}

#example-2 {
    background-color: #4FC1E9;
}

#example-3 {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.fadein .box {
    display: block;
}

.center {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<span ng-app="myApp">
    <section id="example-1" class="container" scroll>
        <div class="box center">
            <h1 class="">Show me when scrolled to this section</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="example-2" class="container" scroll>
        <div class="box center">
            <h1 class="">Show me when scrolled to this section</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="example-3" class="container" scroll>
        <div class="box center">
            <h1 class="">Show me when scrolled to this section</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
</span>
```